# Connect To embedded Access Database in vb2010

Tags: vb.net

Please I need help. I am building an application in VB2010 which uses an Access Database. Evrything went fine but when I published the Application and run, it says the Database cannot be found.. This is the Path I used (Application.StartupPath & "\biology.mdb") to access the database. Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you look at this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kzy0fky2(v=vs.100).aspx

did you include the file(s) in question?

now, when you publish, Application.StartupPath will not work the way you expect it to:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath(v=vs.110).aspx

so you need to change your Application.StartupPath code to something else instead.

take a look here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8saf4wy(v=vs.110).aspx

```
ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.DataDirectory
```

seems to be the suggestion and hint.... read the document in full and you will understand.